# Boost Tokenizer for AT Commands

Tags: c++, boost

I have to parse AT commands from a modem.

Each command has in the form: `[CR][LF]+[CMD][CR][LF]` eg:

```
[CR][LF]+CTCC: 4,1,1,0,0,1,1[CR][LF]

[CR][LF]+CTXG: 4,0,0,0[CR][LF]
```

Since may occur that more than one command is received I thought to use boost::tokenizer to split them, but it seems to not work (it doesn't separate commands):

```
boost::char_separator<char> sep("", "+", boost::keep_empty_tokens);

Tokenizer commands(_buffer, sep);

for (Tokenizer::const_iterator cmd = commands.begin(); 
     cmd != commands.end();
     cmd++)
{
  this->ParseData(*cmd);
}
```

Maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: I'd love to use Spirit for this kind of thing. Are you using Asio?

Comment: Hi @sehe yes, I'm using Asio. I didn't had take into account Spirit before. Maybe for the future. Thanks for the suggestion.